# .NET Core on Linux: Is stdout redirected?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, console

On Windows, I use this code to determine whether the stdout stream is redirected for the currently running process:

```
private static bool? isOutputRedirected;

public static bool IsOutputRedirected
{
    get
    {
        if (isOutputRedirected == null)
        {
            isOutputRedirected =
                GetFileType(GetStdHandle(StdHandle.Output)) != FileType.FileTypeChar ||
                !GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(StdHandle.Output), out _);
            // Additional GetConsoleMode check required to detect redirection to "nul"
        }
        return isOutputRedirected == true;
    }
}

private enum StdHandle : int
{
    Input = -10,
    Output = -11,
    Error = -12,
}

private enum FileType : uint
{
    FileTypeChar = 0x0002,
    FileTypeDisk = 0x0001,
    FileTypePipe = 0x0003,
    FileTypeRemote = 0x8000,
    FileTypeUnknown = 0x0000,
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern FileType GetFileType(IntPtr hFile);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(StdHandle nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
```

I have similar properties for the other two standard streams.

This is required to handle situations when displaying progress info or trying to update the current line with new content. This isn't useful when the output is being redirected, so the output should be reduced to more simple content.

But this fails as expected when running on Linux (`dotnet publish -r linux-arm`).

How can I determine the same situation on Linux? The web doesn't seem to know anything about it (yet).

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core, you might want to look at `Console.IsOutputRedirected` and `Console.IsErrorRedirected`

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netcore-3.1